# Display some text as bold using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

Today I'm working on a graph, and a section of it has annotations using `plt.text`. In this annotation I want to write something along the lines of 
"The price for this month is: **USD$3**"

Which, without bolding, translates into code like this:

```
plt.text(0.5,0.9, f"The price for this month is: USD${df.price.iloc[-1]}")
```

So, what I want to do is to turn the `USD${df.price.iloc[-1]}` into bold when printing into the graph.

There's a similar question in SO, but for the title, that suggested a notation like this one:

```
"The price for this month is:' + r"$\bf{" + USD${df.price.iloc[-1]} + "}$"
```

But it seems that that syntax is invalid, so I'm not sure if it's even possible to have a text that has bold and non-bold parts.

Do you know *if* it can be done and if so, *how* it can be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. You just have to convert the DataFrame value to string

---

**Complete answer**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [2, 4, 8, 3]}, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

fig = plt.figure()

plt.text(0.1,0.9, r"The price for this month is: "+ r"$\bf{USD\$" + str(df.price.iloc[-1])  + "}$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Even concise:**

```
plt.text(0.1,0.9, r"The price for this month is: $\bf{USD\$ %s}$" % str(df.price.iloc[-1]) )
```

**You can also use formatting as**

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.text(0.1,0.9, r"The price for this month is: " + r"$\bf{USD\$" + '{:.2f}'.format(df.price.iloc[-1]) + "}$")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa ! It's working perfectly. I have just one more question: does this syntax support formating? I also have to do this for float numbers and percentages, so I wanted to know if I have to manually format through `np.round()` and multiplying by 100 and adding the "%" ?

Comment: @JuanC: Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks again ! Just to be sure I'm understanding correctly, the `r"$ .... $'` notation let's you use html coding to format your graph's text right?

Comment: `r"$...$"` enables LaTeX rendering

Comment: @JuanC: Have a read at [this](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)

Comment: That's a great resource! Had no idea about that integration. Learning something new every day

Comment: Note that you are not using latex here, but what is called mathtext. The respective documentation for mathtext is [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Absolutely right :) Thanks for the correct link